# Can 'Bend Will' be used on people, animals, etc.?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

According to [wikia](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Bend_Will):

> The second word allows the will of people and animals to be controlled. It makes them temporary allies to the Dragonborn

I have the three words in the shout. Not tried it on dragons yet, but I have tried it on some enemies like Draugr and end bosses in ruins etc. It doesn't work.

Can it actually be done or am I wasting time trying it?

Comment: Draugr and neither people nor animals. There are numerous people in most settlements, why not try it on them?

Comment: @kotekzot I will try it out mate. According to the statements I have read on what it will do then - these may be incorrect. It doesn't do what it says on the tin.

Comment: I believe it won't work on any kind of undead, daedra or automaton, just like Illusion Spells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Bend_Will), the 1st word will let you [cleanse All-Maker Stones](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Cleansing_the_Stones), the 2nd word will let you force NPCs and creatures to become your allies for 30 seconds, and the 3rd word will allow you to force dragons to be your allies and to ride them.

Draugrs aren't NPCs or creatures, they are animated inanimate objects lacking any will, so it's not surprising they cannot be controlled by the Bend Will shout. Additionally, it only seems to work on NPCs that are hostile and unnamed (guard, bandit).

Comment: Draugrs are not objects. They are undead: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Draugr

Comment: @RodrigoGuedes that's sort of my point.

Comment: Yes, I understood. It was just a minor clarification.

Answer (score 0):

In order for it to work on NPC, it has to be hostile ( don't really know that, its just somthing that has been repeated in sevreal websites ) and what it doesent tell you is that u must hold the shout butten. When u tap it ur avatar will only say the first word, same with unreailing force.